# Connecting to Azure from SPFX in team

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams, sharepoint-online, spfx

I have followed this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi) to connect a spfx WebPart to Azure and it's working and it can get data from Azure.
Then I followed this [post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/using-web-part-as-ms-teams-tab) to get my spfx run in the MS Team. The issue is the web part can only connect when it's running in the sharepoint web page or team web page but can not connect to Azure when it's in the Team mobile app or SharePoint app.

The code is available [here](https://github.com/mkokabi/MyAorMessagingWebPart)

Comment: Checking with the code you shared.

Comment: Could you please let us know if your issue is resolved?